# Signature of compact oriented 4-manifold

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

I was told that the signature of $S_1\times F_3$ is zero, where $F_3$ is a  compact oriented 3-manifold. Let $M_4$ be a fibre bundle with $S_1$ as a the base manifold and $F_3$ as the fibre. Assume $M_4$ is oriented. Can one show that the signature of $M_4$ is zero?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, in several ways. It can be proven by cohomological methods (Meyer, ''Die Signatur von Faserbündeln'', PhD thesis in Bonn, early 1970s), L-theory (Lück-Ranicki ''Surgery obstructions if fibre bundles'') or index theory (a footnote in Atiyah ''The signature of fibre-bundles'', the details worked out by myself (arXiv:0902.4719)).
The result is that the signature is multiplicative in oriented fibre bundles of odd fibre dimension. When the base is $S^1$, there is a shorter argument:

Consider the rational Leray-Serre spectral sequence, which collapses for degree reasons. The terms that contribute to the middle dimensional cohomology of $M_4$ are $E_{2}^{0,2}=H^0 (S^1; H^2 (F))$ and $E_{2}^{1,1}=H^1 (S^1 ;H^1 (F))$ (with local coefficients, of course). Now observe that both are dual to each other by Poincare-duality, so in particular have the same dimension. The term $E_{2}^{1,1}=H^1 (S^1 ;H^1 (F))$ is a subgroup of $H^2 (M_4)$. The point now is that the cup product is trivial on this subspace, by the multiplicativity of the spectral sequence.
By the above argument, $dim (E_{2}^{1,1})=1/2 dim H^2 (M_4)$, and so we have found a Lagrangian subspace, in particular, the signature is null.

Comment: Can one prove that the 4-dimensional fibration over $S^1$ is the boundary of a (singular) 5-dimensional fibration over the disc? That would of course imply that the signature is zero, since the 4-manifold would bound a 5-manifold. I was wondering if one could construct the 5-manifold explicitly.

Comment: @Johannes Ebert:  Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: @Bruno Martelli: Thank you very much for the question. I asked a related question here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/142132/fibre-bundle-as-a-boundary-of-a-fibre-bundle

Answer (score 1):

I guess, the tangent bundle has a non-zero section, which is the pull back of
the section from the circle. It means that the first Pontryagin class is zero.
By the [Hirzebruch signature theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirzebruch_signature_theorem) it follows that the signature is zero. Am I right?

Comment: No, you are not; the Pontrjagin class does not have to vanish if there is a section.