# fibre bundle as a boundary of a fibre bundle

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Let $M_{n+1}$ be a fibre bundle with $S_1$ as the base and $n$-dimensional CW complex $F_n$ as the fibre. 
Assume $M_{n+1}$ is oriented.

(1) Can one show that **$M_{n+1}$ is always a boundary of a CW complex $M_{n+2}$,
where $M_{n+2}$ is a fibre bundle with $S_1$ as the base and $(n+1)$-dimensional CW complex $F_{n+1}$ as the fibre**?

(2) Can one show that **$M_{n+1}$ is always a boundary of a CW complex $N_{n+2}$,
where $N_{n+2}$ is a fibre bundle with a disk $D_2$ as the base and $n$-dimensional CW complex $F_{n}$ as the fibre**?

Edit: Based on the discussions below, one needs to replace the term "CW complex" above by term "manifold" or "topological manifold". This maybe the key issue of my question: when (1) will be valid?

Comment: What is "the boundary of a CW complex"?

Comment: CW complex is a type of topological space. So  "the boundary of a CW complex" is the boundary of the topological space.

Comment: Ok, what is the boundary of a topological space?

Comment: For example a disk $D_2$ is a topological space, and $S_1$ is its boundary.

Comment: There is not a good notion of the boundary of a general CW complex.  Do you need spaces that are more general than manifolds?

Comment: @Xiao-GangWen: Of course, there is a notion of boundary for manifolds, homology manifolds and pseudomanifolds. (Disk is a manifold.) But defining boundary for general CW complex let alone topological space, makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: Thank you all for pointing out the difference between topological space, CW complex, and manifold. As a physicist, I have treated them the same. What I need is something continuous, but may not be smooth. I thought CW complex is obtained by glueing the cells (manifolds) together.

Comment: The correct notion is the one of topological manifold, possibly with boundary. No smoothness is assumed here.

Comment: Since the question already has an accepted answer, I would advise you to ask the question in your "Edit" as a separate question if you think it'll get a reasonable answer. As it stands now I doubt many will see this, because most will assume the question has been fully answered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll answer your questions with "CW complex" replaced by "manifold".

The answer to question (1) is no.  If I understand you correctly, you want the boundary of $F_{n+1}$ to be $F_n$.  But some manifolds cannot be realized as boundaries of other manifolds.  (The simplest examples are 4-manifolds with non-zero signature.)

(On the other hand, if we allow $F_{n+1}$ to be a CW complex (and ignore the difficulties of defining what "boundary" means in this context), then the answer to (1) is clearly yes, since we can take $F_{n+1}$ to be the cone on $F_n$.)

The answer to question (2) is also no.  The bundle over $S^1$ is determined by the monodromy $g:F_n\to F_n$.  If $g$ is not isotopic to the identity, then the bundle does not extend over the disk.  And if $g$ is isotopic to the identity, then the bundle is a product.

Comment: Regarding to your answer **we can take $F_{n+1}$ to be the cone on $F_n$**, can the monodromy $g:F_n \to F_n$ (needed to define the  bundle over $S^1$) extended to $F_{n+1}$? Thank you very much.

Comment: I wonder if $F_n$ is a simplicial complex that is equal to its closure, then we can define the boundary of $F_n$. I have always assumed that a complex is equal to its closure. (I wonder if there is name for such kind of complex.)

Comment: You can extend g to the cone in the obvious way: the line between x and the cone point will be mapped to the line between g(x) and the cone point, for all $x\in F_n$.